# Disable threading in django wsgi applciation

Tags: django, wsgi, uwsgi

I'm deploying a django app that uses signals (so it needs to be run in a single thread). I can disable threading in the development server with

`python manage.py runserver --nothreading --noreload`

and it works well. To deploy the app I followed the [django uwsgi deployment guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/wsgi/uwsgi/) and set it up with uwsgi. That is, with

`uwsgi ... -module myapp.wsgi`

How can I disable the uwsgi threading when running the app like this?

**Edit:**
The web application is an online Mathematica interpreter [Mathics](https://mathics.github.io), e.g. http://mathics.angusgriffith.com/. The signal are used to implement evaluation time limits. We're currently using threads but because of the GIL evaluation can get 'stuck' since everything is CPU bound. We also tried using multiprocessing but the overhead was too high. [Link to the Mathics signals code](https://github.com/mathics/Mathics/blob/master/mathics/core/evaluation.py#L47).

Comment: Why do signals mean it needs to be run in a single thread? What kind of signals do you mean?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, Python signals e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html, specifically signal.SIGALRM (or unix alarm). Otherwise I get `ValueError: signal only works in main thread`.

Comment: Sounds like an odd thing to be doing in a web application. But in any case, Django doesn't have anything to do with threading; you will need to look at the uwsgi configuration docs.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, maybe I wasn't clear. This problem occurs without uwsgi but I can pass the `--nothreading` and `--noreload` arguments to disable threading in django. To quote the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/django-admin/) "The server is multithreaded by default". I want to know how I can pass the arguments to django when launching the app with uwsgi.

Comment: I don't quite understand why you would want a web application to be single threaded, You've said its so you can use some python signal but *what* is that signal supposed to be doing? do you need the signal?. `runserver` is only to be used when developing a website, you shouldn't take its arguments as something that a live version should be capable of doing.

Comment: @Sayse I've added some details to the question to explain the motivation.

Comment: No, you were perfectly clear. Those options refer to the Django development server, which you are not using; you are using uwsgi. Django *by itself* has no threading options, and in fact does not have any concept of threading. The threading is being done by the server.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, Ah, I didn't realise that was specific to the development server, thanks for clarifying that. In that case it seems that I just want to disable uwsgi threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking to account your explanation why you need signals in Django application, in my opinion you're doing something terribly wrong.

If you're just starting computation inside your view, that can take long time, you're freezing whole worker for that time. That means, worker can't process any other request. If you're using 4 workers and there will be 5 users that will submit equation that needs more computation, there won't be resources to process request from one of them, because all 4 workers will be busy computing.

That means, for larger amount of users you will need lot of workers. Each worker will consume resources and you will run out of them very, very fast.

In other words, it is very bad practice to run some long tasks inside views.

Consider using some task queue like celery, send every equation to solve into celery. That way you workers will be available all the time to handle requests and task will be queued. Also it will be lot easier to manage frozen tasks.

Answer (score 1):

To disable threading when deploying with uwsgi, in your `uwsgi.ini` file set `threads` to `1`, this will limit the script to run in single thead per each process:

```
[uwsgi]
processes = 4
threads = 1
```

So this way you can use several processes, each running single thread.